# Not able to submit request On IE in GateIn portal

Tags: java, servlets, portlet, jboss6.x, gatein

I have a GateIn portal based application, where I am submitting a offline form (a HTML form, submitted using javascript).

I am POSTing my form submit to a `Servlet`. The `Servlet` checks whether user is logged in. If user is not logged then it redirects the user to login page, parses the form data and save it in session and shows the login page. From the login page user put credentials and submit it. In login portlet the saved session data is not available

The same thing is working in mozilla.

`Servlet` from where redirection to login Page is made:

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest aoRequest, HttpServletResponse aoResponse) throws ServletException, IOException
{
  MOLOGWRAPPER.info("SPEFormServiceServlet doPost start");
  Map<String, Object> loHMForm = null;
  String lsIsOffline = null;
  String lsServiceName = null;
  String lsApplicantId = null;
  lsIsOffline = (String) aoRequest.getParameter("Offline");
  String lsTimeStamp = null;
  long loTimeStamp;
  String lsContentPath = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
  if (null != aoRequest.getParameter("formAction") && "fromLogin".equalsIgnoreCase(aoRequest.getParameter("formAction")))
  {
    loHMForm = (Map<String, Object>) aoRequest.getSession().getAttribute("OfflineData");
  }
  //MOLOGWRAPPER.info("LoHM after login in servlet "+loHMForm);
  String msUserId = null;
  if (null != aoRequest.getUserPrincipal())
    msUserId = aoRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName();
  HttpSession moSession = aoRequest.getSession();
  try
  {
    if (null != aoRequest.getParameter("serviceName"))
    {
      lsServiceName = aoRequest.getParameter("serviceName").trim();
    }
    lsApplicantId = aoRequest.getParameter("applicantId");
    // Getting unique time stamp for per user per service
    if (null != aoRequest.getParameter("timestamp"))
    {
      lsTimeStamp = aoRequest.getParameter("timestamp").trim();
      loTimeStamp = Long.parseLong(aoRequest.getParameter("timestamp"));
    } else
    {
      loTimeStamp = (new Date()).getTime();
      lsTimeStamp = String.valueOf(loTimeStamp);
      aoRequest.setAttribute("TMAttachment", lsTimeStamp);
    }
    if (null != lsIsOffline && lsIsOffline.equals("Y"))
    {
      if (null == msUserId)
      {
        try
        {
          MOLOGWRAPPER.info("SPEFormServiceServlet in logout block msUserId:" + msUserId);
          MOLOGWRAPPER.info("SPEFormServiceServlet in logout block SessionID:" + aoRequest.getSession().getId());
          aoRequest.logout();
        } catch (ServletException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        aoRequest.getSession().setAttribute("OfflineData", loHMForm);
        aoRequest.setAttribute("OfflineData", loHMForm);
        aoResponse.sendRedirect(aoRequest.getScheme() + "://" + aoRequest.getServerName() + ":" + aoRequest.getServerPort() + "/portal/portal/Login?offlineFlag=y&FromForm=y&sp_serviceName=" + lsServiceName);
        return;
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception e)
  {

  }
}
```

Login Portlet:

- `doView`:

```java
public void doView(RenderRequest aoRequest, RenderResponse aoResponse)
    throws PortletException, IOException
{

  RenderRequestImpl renderRequest = (RenderRequestImpl) aoRequest;
  HttpServletRequestWrapper httpReq = renderRequest.getRealRequest();
  String serviceName = httpReq.getParameter("sp_serviceName");
  aoRequest.setAttribute("sp_serviceName", serviceName);
  String offlineFlag = httpReq.getParameter("offlineFlag");
  aoRequest.setAttribute("sp_offlineFlag", offlineFlag);
  String fromFrom = httpReq.getParameter("FromForm");
  aoRequest.setAttribute("FromForm", fromFrom);

  PortletSession moSession = aoRequest.getPortletSession();

  if (null != httpReq.getParameter("FromForm") && "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(fromFrom))
  {
    moSession.setAttribute("OfflineData",
        httpReq.getSession().getAttribute("OfflineData"),
        PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
  }

  lscsrfVal = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(40);
  moSession.setAttribute("csrfVal", lscsrfVal);
  aoRequest.setAttribute("csrfVal", lscsrfVal);
  logger.info("lscsrfVal :: " + lscsrfVal);
  logger.info("moSession : Doview id :: " + moSession.getId());
}
```

- `processAction`:

```java
public void processAction(ActionRequest aoRequest, ActionResponse aoResponse)
    throws PortletException
{

  PortletSession moSession = aoRequest.getPortletSession();
  logger.info("moSession : Process Action id :: " + moSession.getId());
  logger.info("csrfVal == " + moSession.getAttribute("csrfVal"));
  HttpServletRequest req = Util.getPortalRequestContext().getRequest();
  HttpSession moHttpSession = req.getSession();
  moHttpSession.getAttribute("csrfVal");
  logger.info("moHttpSession : Process Action id :: " + moHttpSession.getId());
  logger.info("moHttpSession : Process Action OfflineData ::"
      + moHttpSession.getAttribute("OfflineData"));

  if (null != moSession.getAttribute("csrfVal")
      && null != aoRequest.getParameter("sp_csrf")
      && aoRequest.getParameter("sp_csrf").equals(moSession.getAttribute("csrfVal")))
  {
    logger.info("request is valid");
    moSession.removeAttribute("csrfVal");
  } else
  {
    moSession.setAttribute("csrfValErr", "true");
    logger.info("request is invalid :: Redirect to Login");
    return;
  }
}
```

Logs:

```
15:37:41,387 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPEFormServiceServlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) SPEFormServiceServlet in logout block msUserId:null
15:37:41,387 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPEFormServiceServlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) SPEFormServiceServlet in logout block SessionID:k4dIpdc1Dqiadh4ZMCGTQaeN

15:37:44,418 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) SPUserActionPortlet : doView : start
15:37:45,287 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) lscsrfVal :: PLlmfohMhtPBkO2Qt7HAQAMQsdaAg5qsEWCII8aP
15:37:45,287 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) moSession : Doview id :: NC9VLsKmqKPuev2AA304RMTU
15:37:45,287 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) SPUserActionPortlet : doView : end

15:38:07,471 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) SPUserActionPortlet : processAction : Start
15:38:07,491 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) moSession : Process Action id :: o8t09QtNv7-fpR0hcP7uXs1g
15:38:07,491 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) csrfVal == null
15:38:07,491 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) moHttpSession : Process Action id :: o8t09QtNv7-fpR0hcP7uXs1g
15:38:07,491 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) moHttpSession : Process Action OfflineData :: null
15:38:07,491 INFO  [com.abc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-1) request is invalid :: Redirect to Login
```

**EDIT**

doView Method with HttpServletRequest httpReq=Util.getPortalRequestContext().getRequest();

```
public void doView(RenderRequest aoRequest, RenderResponse aoResponse)
            throws PortletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq=Util.getPortalRequestContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession moHttpSession =httpReq.getSession();
        String serviceName=httpReq.getParameter("sp_serviceName");
        aoRequest.setAttribute("sp_serviceName", serviceName);
        String offlineFlag=httpReq.getParameter("offlineFlag");
        aoRequest.setAttribute("sp_offlineFlag", offlineFlag);
        String fromFrom=httpReq.getParameter("FromForm");
        aoRequest.setAttribute("FromForm", fromFrom);
        PortletSession moSession = aoRequest.getPortletSession();
        if(null!=httpReq.getParameter("FromForm") && "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(fromFrom)){
            moSession.setAttribute("OfflineData", httpReq.getSession().getAttribute("OfflineData"), PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
        }

        lscsrfVal =  RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(40);
        moSession.setAttribute("csrfVal",lscsrfVal);
        aoRequest.setAttribute("csrfVal",lscsrfVal);
        MOLOGWRAPPER.info("lscsrfVal :: "+lscsrfVal);
        MOLOGWRAPPER.info("moSession : Doview id :: "+moSession.getId());

    }
```

Logs: in doView:

```
11:56:05,636 INFO  [com.acc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-2) SPUserActionPortlet : doView : start
11:56:05,637 INFO  [com.acc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-2) lscsrfVal :: TsUGvRcevcuSeo4a7daqhl2bjU6lJf9Cg6MNLgYn
11:56:05,637 INFO  [com.acc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-2) moSession : Doview id :: 7jxf2nzyatjdxYgoMYYGHKyj
11:56:05,637 INFO  [com.acc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-2) SPUserActionPortlet : doView : end
```

Logs: in processAction:

```
11:56:37,526 INFO  [com.acc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-5) moSession : Process Action id :: -r96FXye5MlDW+xsEjUgKbzV
11:56:37,527 INFO  [com.acc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-5) csrfVal == null
11:56:37,527 INFO  [com.acc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-5) moHttpSession : Process Action id :: -r96FXye5MlDW+xsEjUgKbzV
11:56:37,528 INFO  [com.acc.sp.action.SPUserActionPortlet] (ajp-/127.0.0.1:8009-5) moHttpSession : Process Action OfflineData :: null
```

Answer (score 0):

The portlet specification (JSR-168 and JSR-286) states the portlet lifecycle, and it should flow as below:

> init -> processAction -> render -> destroy

The `doView` method is executed when the portal container fires the render process **and** the portal is in view mode. Thus this method is invoked after the `processAction` method.
So try to reverse the wheel and set your session attributes inside the `processAction` method and not in the `doView` one.

Comment: The portlet is just there on the user's login page, and hence doView will be called first. There is no way to call processAction directly. processAction will only be called once user does any action on that portlet. Also refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330969/understanding-the-execution-of-action-phase-and-render-phase

Comment: You should have pointed that into your OP. By the way whay is `aoRequest` in the login redirection servlet?
Could you provide all your code with method signature.

Comment: aoRequest is HttpServletRequest in Servlet class, RenderRequest in doView Method and ActionRequest in processAction method of login Portlet class.

Comment: Could you please try to retrieve the `HttpRequest` in the *doView* method just the same way you did in the *processAction* method: replacing "`HttpServletRequestWrapper httpReq = renderRequest.getRealRequest();`" with "`HttpServletRequest httpReq = Util.getPortalRequestContext().getRequest();`"

Comment: I have updated doView method accordingly, still not able to get data in processAction.